# extract the text values from html response nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, parsing, web-scraping

I have a scenario, where I am trying to extract the values for following text in html and store in a variable.
As of now I have tried [Cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio)
But it doesn't seem to work.

HTML :

```
var htmlbody = <table style="width:100%; border: 1px solid #cccccc; border-collapse: collapse;" border=1 cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4"><tr><td style="background-color: #eeeeee; width: 200px;">Improvement Date (first date)</td><td>Nov 5, 2019 1:57:00 PM UTC</td></tr><tr><td style="background-color: #eeeeee">Document Call existed at</td><td>Nov 5, 2019 3:40:00 PM UTC</td></tr><tr><td style="background-color: #eeeeee">Document creation at</td><td>not available</td></tr><tr><td style="background-color: #eeeeee; width: 200px;">First document sent</td><td>not available</td></tr></table>
```

What I have tried here

```
   const cheerio = require('cheerio')
   var html = htmlbody
   const txt = $(html).text()
   console.log(txt)
```

I want to extract this below values from the html individually in exact order and store in a variable individually.

```
Nov 5, 2019 1:57:00 PM UTC
Nov 5, 2019 3:40:00 PM UTC
not available
not available
```

Note : HTML snippet that I have will not have any class or id assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by parsing through the content. Please refer to the code below.

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

var htmlbody = '<table style="width:100%; border: 1px solid #cccccc; border-collapse: collapse;" border=1 cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4"><tr><td style="background-color: #eeeeee; width: 200px;">Improvement Date (first date)</td><td>Nov 5, 2019 1:57:00 PM UTC</td></tr><tr><td style="background-color: #eeeeee">Document Call existed at</td><td>Nov 5, 2019 3:40:00 PM UTC</td></tr><tr><td style="background-color: #eeeeee">Document creation at</td><td>not available</td></tr><tr><td style="background-color: #eeeeee; width: 200px;">First document sent</td><td>not available</td></tr></table>';

const $ = cheerio.load(htmlbody);

var html = $('table').children();
var tr = $("tr", html);
var val = {};
for(var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    var td = $("td", tr[i]);
    val[$(td[0]).html()] = $(td[1]).html();
}
// The extracted values are stored in key value pair
// 'Improvement Date (first date)': 'Nov 5, 2019 1:57:00 PM UTC',
// 'Document Call existed at': 'Nov 5, 2019 3:40:00 PM UTC',
// 'Document creation at': 'not available',
// 'First document sent': 'not available'
console.log(val);
```

Comment: its giving error `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: This is based on jQuery framework. You have to import the jquery script  by adding the script - <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @Thomas I have put up the code that will help you get the text above. See if this helps.

Comment: two questions here wrt. your code :
1--  Is the order of loop executed here is same as the one we have in elements ?
2-- I want to store the elements individually not in a stack how can I do that ?

Comment: I had to run a loop for iterating over the columns and then one loop to iterate over the row. When you iterate over the row, you have to sequentially extract values and store it in whatever way you like. Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: Also, I'm not storing the result in  a stack. I'm just printing the results. You can store it in whatever way you please. I can help you with the code if you let me know what exactly you want to do.

Comment: okay if you see in the HTML body there are four sections those are present here
 
`Improvement Date (first date), Document Call existed at, Document creation at,First document sent`
For these keys we are extracting the values from table below
`Nov 5, 2019 1:57:00 PM UTC
Nov 5, 2019 3:40:00 PM UTC
not available
not available`
So I want to extract them sequentially and store in 4 individual variables

Comment: @Thomas I have made some edits in the code to extract and store the values in a key value pairs. Check if this works?